# do thrust::min_element on arrays on the gpu

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I am trying to find the minimum of an array which is on the gpu. I can use min_element on things on the cpu, but not sure how to do it on things on the gpu. Also I am confused why the return of min_element has to be an array since there's only one minimum? this is the closest to what I think is correct, but I get : 
' error: no suitable conversion function from "thrust::device_ptr" to "double *" exists ' for the min_element line.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for rand() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for getpid() */
#include <time.h> /* for time() */
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

bool errorAsk(const char *s="n/a")
{
cudaError_t err=cudaGetLastError();
if(err==cudaSuccess)
    return false;
printf("CUDA error [%s]: %s\n",s,cudaGetErrorString(err));
return true;
};

double *fillArray(double *c_idata,int N,double constant) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            c_idata[n] = constant*floor(drand48()*10);

    }
return c_idata;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int N;
    N = 100;

    double *c_data,*g_data,*result;
    result = new double[N];

    c_data = new double[N];
    c_data = fillArray(c_data,N,1);

    cudaMalloc(&g_data,N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(g_data,c_data,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    thrust::device_ptr<double> g_ptr =  thrust::device_pointer_cast(g_data);

    result = thrust::min_element(g_ptr, g_ptr + N); // not sure how to get this to work
//        result = thrust::max_element(c_data, c_data + N); //works but I need to do this on the gpu

    cudaMemcpy(c_data,g_data,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cout<<result[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The return value from min_element isn't an array. It is a forward iterator which points to the entry in the array which holds the min value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`thrust::min_element`  returns an *iterator*.

From the [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__extrema.html#gaa9dcee5e36206a3ef7215a4b3984e002):

> min_element finds the smallest element in the range [first, last). It returns the first **iterator** i in [first, last) such that no other iterator in [first, last) points to a value smaller than *i.

An iterator is something like a pointer. It indicates a position of an element in a container.  Like pointers, iterators can be added to, subtracted from, etc.

So we could extract this iterator directly:

```
thrust::device_ptr<double> result_position = thrust::min_element(...
```

or another approach would be to get a relative offset to that position, from the start of the container:

```
int result_offset = thrust::min_element(g_ptr, ...) - g_ptr;
```

This works because iterators (or `thrust::device_ptr`) can be subtracted.  The iterator returned from `min_element` minus the start of the container will give the offset to the position of the minimum element.

Here's a worked example based on your code:

```
$ cat t957.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for rand() */
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

using namespace std;

bool errorAsk(const char *s="n/a")
{
cudaError_t err=cudaGetLastError();
if(err==cudaSuccess)
    return false;
printf("CUDA error [%s]: %s\n",s,cudaGetErrorString(err));
return true;
};

double *fillArray(double *c_idata,int N,double constant) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            c_idata[n] = constant*floor(drand48()*10.0);

    }
return c_idata;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int N;
    N = 100;

    double *c_data,*g_data;
//    result = new double[N];

    c_data = new double[N];
    c_data = fillArray(c_data,N,1.0);
    c_data[32] = -1.0;
    cudaMalloc(&g_data,N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(g_data,c_data,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    thrust::device_ptr<double> g_ptr =  thrust::device_pointer_cast(g_data);

    int result_offset = thrust::min_element(g_ptr, g_ptr + N) - g_ptr;

    double min_value = *(g_ptr + result_offset);
    // we could also do this:
    // double min_value = c_data[result_offset];
    std::cout<< "min value found at position: " << result_offset << " value: " << min_value << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t957 t957.cu
$ ./t957
min value found at position: 32 value: -1
$
```

The [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) gives a brief description of iterators and their usage in thrust.